# Change docstrings output format

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a below example model

```
class example(models.Model):
    """This is the summary of the example

    This is the description of the example
    :param first: First parameter
    :type filed1: String
    :param second: Second parameter
    :type field2: String
    """    
    filed1 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

This is being rendered by **Sphinx** as below

```
class kyc_connect.models.example(*args, **kwargs)[source]¶

    This is the summary of the example

    This is the description of the example :param first: First parameter :type filed1: String :param second: Second parameter :type field2: String
```

Which looks really bad given all param are coagulated on the single line. Is this the default behavior or I am doing something wrong, can I do something to change output in different format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters in [info field lists](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#info-field-lists) must be separated with whitespace of two blank lines from the description within the docstring.

```
class example(models.Model):
    """This is the summary of the example

    This is the description of the example

    :param first: First parameter
    :type field1: String
    :param second: Second parameter
    :type field2: String
    """    
    filed1 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I also fixed the typo for `type field1`.

Comment: If the parameters are called `first` and `second`, it should be `:type first:` and `:type second:`.